# how to integrate multiple language in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i want to integrate multiple language in zend project.for that i have studied http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.translate.using.html but..from that i didn't get idea of how it can be done..even it doesn't show on which page i have write code.in which page what code should..i am so,confuse..can anyone give me idea how i can integrate language with zend so my site can be translated in any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but it may be useful for you.

> Multiple adapters are available in ZF you can choose anyone
>   Zend_Transalate adapters Array, Csv, Gettext, Ini, Tbx, Tmx, Qt,
>   Xliff.
>
> for CSV
>
> 1) Create a different CSV files for each languages that you are going
>   to use.  eg : `en.csv` `hn.csv`
>
> 2) Create constants for each word/sentence that you are going to use
>   in your application. Save all the constants and their values into
>   their respective CSV. eg : `constant` `value`
>
> 3) Load the language file

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate('csv', "/pathtofile/$lngfile.csv", 'en');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
```

You can carry `$lngfile` variable in the URL eg: `/en/controller/action/`

> 4) For showing translated values in phtml `$this->translate('constant_name');`